# Resource utilization Headless Server vs. Headless Desktop (20.04)

Tags: server, 20.04, desktop-environments

I use a headless Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 system for CPU intensive simulations (Intel 6th Gen Core i7, 32GB RAM, 1TB SSD, Intel integrated graphics).  Access and programming is all performed via SSH, no monitor is connected to the system. The system boots to the GUI login screen.

Is there any difference or potential to squeeze out a bit more performance or to lower thermal output if I move to a headless 20.04.3 Ubuntu server version?

If both systems are to be used via SSH, is a monitorless Desktop system (showing only the login screen) worse than a monitorless Server system performance or thermal wise?

Comment: Can you add the specs?

Comment: Intel 6th Gen Core i7, 32GB RAM, 1TB SSD, Intel integrated graphics

Comment: A server system has no desktop; meaning desktop applications are not running, those libraries etc won't be using memory etc.. leaving more resources available for the server system you are using. Desktops are *heavy*, which is why they're not included by default on a server install - where performance is the goal.

Comment: @guiverc I understand your comment. However the question is , is a monitor-less Desktop system with only the login screen on worse than a headless server?

Comment: The desktop stack is not running nor occupying resources until somebody logs into the GUI login prompt or starts a remote GUI session. If nobody is doing that, then there is likely to be no noticeable performance or thermal benefit to migrating.